# Android HttpPost failes - server receives null query string parameter

Tags: android, wcf, http, rest, http-post

I have a simple WCF web service on my machine which I have developed to serve Android and IOS devices.

The service has a single method as following :

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "/?message={message}")]
    string ServiceMessage(string message);
```

I have 3 clients , one .NET test client using HttpWebRequest which works fine , one IOS client which works fine and one Android client which I have developed with the HttpPost and HttpClient classes that fails.

Using Fiddler reverse proxy I have debugged the output of the .net client :

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8888/Service1.svc/?message=_|JSON MESSAGE BODY|_HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
Content-Length: 338
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

_|JSON MESSAGE BODY|_
```

On the other hand , this is the output of the Android HTTP Post :

```
POST http://10.0.2.2:8888/Service1.svc/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 139
Host: 10.0.2.2:8888
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)
Expect: 100-Continue

message=_|JSON MESSAGE BODY|_
```

As you can see , .Net puts the message parameter on the Post at the top and does not 
put the message variable name at the bottom while Android does not put the message body at the Post at the top and does put the message variable name at the bottom.

This is my Android post code ,

```
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);      
    String messageBody = "message=" + jsonMessageParameter;
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(messageBody);
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    HttpResponse response = hc.execute(httpPost);
    InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();
    String json = ConvertStreamToString(content);
```

When calling with this code , the server method is called but the message method parameter is null.
I tried playing with the Uri.Builder class to also make the android post put the message at the header , but doesnt quite work.
If can someone help me out here , I am stuck on this for hours over hours.

Thank you in advance ,

James

EDIT :

I changed the Android code to :

```
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", jsonMessageParameter));

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
     UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFromEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
     nameValuePairs);
     urlEncodedFromEntity.setContentType(new BasicHeader("Content-Type",
     "application/json; charset=utf-8"));

    httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFromEntity);

    InputStream postStream = httpPost.getEntity().getContent();
    String postOutput = ConvertStreamToString(postStream);
    HttpResponse response = hc.execute(httpPost);
    InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();
    String json = ConvertStreamToString(content);
```

But still the Fiddler monitoring is as following :

```
POST http://10.0.2.2:8888/Service1.svc/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 189
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: 10.0.2.2:8888
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)
Expect: 100-Continue

message=_|MESSAGE_JSON|_
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a number of points here.

First, you specifically added `message=` to your Android POST body:

```
String messageBody = "message=" + jsonMessageParameter;
```

This can be also problematic since you specified `Content-Type: application/json` but by adding `message=` you are not providing a valid JSON object.

Second, why does the .Net implementation replicate the JSON object both as parameter in the URL and in the body? This looks strange and very uncommon for a POST request, and can cause problem if your JSON object makes the URL exceed the maximum URL length.

So I would try removing `message=` in the body and removing the JSON object as a URL parameter, since servers processing POSTs should read the body and not the URL.

Comment: But what if the service method receives several query string parameters , how then do you post it ?

Comment: Use a UrlEncodedFormEntity instead of StringEntity, which will produce a body like param1=value1&param2=value2...

Comment: In the end it seems I didnt read JSON correct in the server side.
The only way that worked for me is to receive a Stream object on the server side , this allows me to read the message body .

Answer (score 0):

HttpPost is for posting, afaik.

```
String url;
input = url + URLEncoder.encode(messageBody, "utf-8");
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(input);
InputStream stream = httpclient.execute(httpget).getEntity().getContent();
String s = streamToString(stream);
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(s);
```

This very exact code (plus some try/catch) works for me for querying GoogleBooks, probably you can adapt it to your service with little effort?

Best regards.

Comment: But what if the service method receives several query string parameters , how then do you post it ?